# Bug in Entity Framework Core 3.1 when grouping using a key with a division?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to group a set of data using linq and entity framework 3.1. This is the query I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var query = dbset
                .Join(vehicles,
                    i => i.VehicleId,
                    v => v.Id,
                    (i, v) => new{i, v})
                .Where(o=>o.v.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId && o.i.ReportDate>=startDate && o.i.ReportDate<=endDate);

dateDataQuery = query.GroupBy(o =>
                    new
                    {
                        Week=(int)(o.i.ReportDate.DayOfYear / 7),
                        o.i.ReportDate.Year
                    })
                    .OrderBy(o=> o.Key.Year).ThenBy(o=>o.Key.Week)
                    .Select(g => new TransferDateData()
                    {
                        Week = g.Key.Week,
                        Year = g.Key.Year,
                        Value = g.Sum(o=>o.i.Cost),
                    });
```

As you can see I am grouping by Week and Year. The problem is that DateTime doesn't have a Week property to get the week of the year that could be translatable to a database procedure. As we can do with .Month or .Day. So, the week must be calculated.

This query outputs different results with same Week and Year. For example I can have several results like:

```
{ Week = 20, Year=2020, Value = 20}, {Week=20, Year=2020, Value=30} ...
```

As you can see they should have been grouped but they don't. If I use a hardcoded number for the week in the grouping, the gropuing works and all values are aggregated and only a result returned.

So, I guess there is a problem with the division and the float result although Week is a int.

Here are the two models I'm using and their properties:

```
public class GenericDateData<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
}

public class TransferDateData : GenericDateData<float>
{
    public float TotalKm { get; set; }
}
```

Could you guess what is happening? Seems a bug to me.

Comment: The problem is the query itself. If it works, it will be *very* slow and require a full table scan just to calculate the week number. Which won't be valid anyway - calculating the week number is a bit more complex than just dividing by 7. The easy way to perform such queries in SQL is to use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a pre-calculated table with dates for eg the next 20 years, with fields for year, month, day of month, week number, quarters, semesters or any other reporting period you want

Comment: In any case, you're using LINQ as if it was SQL or a replacement for it. It's not. It's the *ORM's* job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities. If you have to use JOINs in LINQ, something is probably wrong. Either there are missing relations, or EF Core shouldn't be used at all. ORMs (like EF Core and NHibernate) are **not** meant for reporting queries, they're meant to Map Objects to Relational tables. It's better to write a SQL view or function and map the results to your report objects

Comment: While i disagree that using a join is _wrong_ (there are many valid cases for this), it is true that there are also many cases where navigation properties can achieve the same thing. Personally, I would refactor the week calculation into a user defined function (database-side) as well. However, this is unrelated to the actual question, which is not about what is the best way to implement this, but about if this query can be made workable, or if it is an unsupported scenario (or even a bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does work. As mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos in the comments, it is *inaccurate*, but it *does translate* into valid SQL:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class Incident
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
        public float Cost { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enterprise
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class GenericDateData<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransferDateData : GenericDateData<float>
    {
        public float TotalKm { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enterprise> Enterprises { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63118907")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Incident>().HasData(
                new Incident {Id = 1, VehicleId = 1, ReportDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), Cost = 42.00f},
                new Incident {Id = 2, VehicleId = 2, ReportDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1), Cost = 21.00f});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasData(
                new Vehicle {Id = 1, EnterpriseId = 1},
                new Vehicle {Id = 2, EnterpriseId = 1});
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>().HasData(
                new Enterprise {Id = 1});
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var enterpriseId = 1;
            var startDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
            var endDate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 31);

            var costPerWeek = context.Incidents
                .Join(
                    context.Vehicles,
                    i => i.VehicleId,
                    v => v.Id,
                    (i, v) => new {i, v})
                .Where(
                    o => o.v.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId &&
                         o.i.ReportDate >= startDate &&
                         o.i.ReportDate <= endDate)
                .GroupBy(
                    o =>
                        new
                        {
                            Week = (int) (o.i.ReportDate.DayOfYear / 7),
                            o.i.ReportDate.Year
                        })
                .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Year)
                .ThenBy(o => o.Key.Week)
                .Select(
                    g => new TransferDateData()
                    {
                        Week = g.Key.Week,
                        Year = g.Key.Year,
                        Value = g.Sum(o => o.i.Cost),
                    })
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[0].Week == 0);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[0].Value == 42.00f);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[1].Week == 4);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[1].Value == 21.00f);
        }
    }
}
```

The query gets translated to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT DATEPART(dayofyear, [i].[ReportDate]) / 7 AS [Week], DATEPART(year, [i].[ReportDate]) AS [Year], CAST(SUM([i].[Cost]) AS real) AS [Value]
FROM [Incidents] AS [i]
INNER JOIN [Vehicles] AS [v] ON [i].[VehicleId] = [v].[Id]
WHERE (([v].[EnterpriseId] = @__enterpriseId_0) AND ([i].[ReportDate] >= @__startDate_1)) AND ([i].[ReportDate] <= @__endDate_2)
GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, [i].[ReportDate]) / 7, DATEPART(year, [i].[ReportDate])
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, [i].[ReportDate]), DATEPART(dayofyear, [i].[ReportDate]) / 7
```

It currently starts counting the weeks from `0` though, and despite that, the date can be off (depending on how the calendar week is calculated in the culture this app is being used) by a couple of days.

---

A simpler and more accurate solution might be to use the [DATEPART(week, @date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) T-SQL function. Unfortunately, there is currently no .NET Core method that gets translated to this SQL function.

You can however define a UDF (user defined function) that redirects the call to `DATEPART`.

The following example does not only define a UDF and uses it, but also shows how to use navigation properties instead of explicit joins:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class Incident
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
        public float Cost { get; set; }
        
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Incident> Incidents { get; set; } = new HashSet<Incident>();
    }

    public class Enterprise
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class GenericDateData<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransferDateData : GenericDateData<float>
    {
        public float TotalKm { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enterprise> Enterprises { get; set; }

        // Define your UDF:
        [DbFunction("GetCalendarWeek")]
        public static int GetCalendarWeek(DateTime date)
            => throw new InvalidOperationException("Should never be called but only translated to SQL.");

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63118907_01")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Incident>().HasData(
                new Incident {Id = 1, VehicleId = 1, ReportDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), Cost = 42.00f},
                new Incident {Id = 2, VehicleId = 2, ReportDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1), Cost = 21.00f});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasData(
                new Vehicle {Id = 1, EnterpriseId = 1},
                new Vehicle {Id = 2, EnterpriseId = 1});
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>().HasData(
                new Enterprise {Id = 1});
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Since this example recreates the database on each run,
            // lets create our UDF here as well:
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@"
CREATE FUNCTION [GetCalendarWeek] (@date DATETIME)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEPART(week, @date);
END");

            var enterpriseId = 1;
            var startDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
            var endDate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 31);

            var costPerWeek = context.Incidents
                .Include(i => i.Vehicle)
                .Include(i => i.Enterprise)
                .Where(
                    i => i.Vehicle.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId &&
                         i.ReportDate >= startDate &&
                         i.ReportDate <= endDate)
                .GroupBy(
                    i =>
                        new
                        {
                            // Let's call our UDF here:
                            Week = Context.GetCalendarWeek(i.ReportDate),
                            i.ReportDate.Year
                        })
                .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Year)
                .ThenBy(o => o.Key.Week)
                .Select(
                    g => new TransferDateData()
                    {
                        Week = g.Key.Week,
                        Year = g.Key.Year,
                        Value = g.Sum(i => i.Cost),
                    })
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[0].Week == 1);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[0].Value == 42.00f);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[1].Week == 5);
            Debug.Assert(costPerWeek[1].Value == 21.00f);
        }
    }
}
```

The week numbers are correct (depending on your culture) now.

The generated SQL is petty simple now:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [GetCalendarWeek] (@date DATETIME)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEPART(week, @date);
END

SELECT [dbo].[GetCalendarWeek]([i].[ReportDate]) AS [Week], DATEPART(year, [i].[ReportDate]) AS [Year], CAST(SUM([i].[Cost]) AS real) AS [Value]
FROM [Incidents] AS [i]
INNER JOIN [Vehicles] AS [v] ON [i].[VehicleId] = [v].[Id]
```